# Detect if php file is being used in <link> or <script> tag

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have a PHP file called `styles.php?id=1`. This fetches CSS code from MySQL and using `Content-type: text/css`. It can be used with `<link>` tag.

If I use `.htaccess` to rewrite engine, then it would be `/styles/1`. I have a similar file which fetches js (`/scripts/1`) code instead.

Instead I want one file called `code.php` which can detect which tag it is being used in and fetch the code from the database.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible. Stick to two separate files and two separate rewrites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been quite a while but I got an answer. Just thought to share it with other people who need something similar to this.

**In .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^code/(\w+).(\w+)$ code.php?id=$1&type=$2
```

And In PHP, I would check if the parameter type is equal to CSS or JS and set the content-type header

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. HTTP request to your server does not contain the tag that caused it.

The only way is to include what you want into GET.

Pseudocode:

```
if (isset($_GET['js'])) {
    echo (getJavascriptFromDB());
} elseif (isset($_GET['css'])) {
    echo (getCSSFromDB());
} else {
    die("Invalid");
}
```

HTML:

```
<link href="code.php?css=1" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="code.js?js=1"></script>
```